# Compilation error with Java Generics: Required type 'capture of ? extends MyInterface' when passing object implementing MyInterface

Tags: java, generics, interface, parameterized

I have defined the class:

```
public abstract class AbstractFruitHandler<T extends Fruit> {
   public abstract void handle(T fruit);
   ...
}
```

Where `Fruit` is an interface.

Example of a class that extends this abstract class:

```
public class AppleHandler extends AbstractFruitHandler<Apple> {
    @Override
    public void handle(Apple a) {
             ...
         }
    }
}
```

Where `Apple` is a class that implements `Fruit`.

I have defined a map of these fruit handlers as such:

```
Map<FruitType, AbtractFruitHandler<? extends Fruit> handlers = Map.of(
     FruitType.APPLE, new AppleHandler(),
     FruitType.BANANA, new BananaHandler()
);
```

Now here is where I begin to see issues. Consider the code below:

```
for (Fruit f : fruits) {
    AbstractFruitHandler handler = handlers.get(f.getType());
    handler.handle(f);
}
```

This code works fine! The only issue is that the IDE warns about `Raw use of parameterized class 'AbstractFruitHandler'`.

To suppress this warning, I tried to update this code to:

```
for (Fruit f : fruits) {
    AbstractFruitHandler<? extends Fruit> handler = handlers.get(f.getType());
    handler.handle(f);
}
```

But then I get a compilation error saying that the required type of the `handle` method is `capture of ? extends Fruit`, and not the provided type `Fruit`.

I should also note that I get the same error when I try to explicitly pass in a concrete implementation of `Fruit`.

If possible, I'd like to know why I see this compilation error even though I am passing in objects that are a subtype of `Fruit`.

I'm also wondering what other possible solutions there are.

Comment: Despite the map, which should logically prevent you from passing the incorrect fruit to a fruit handler, the compiler only sees an `AbstractFruitHandler<?>` and a `Fruit`. What if the type of `f` was `Banana` and the type of `handler` was `AppleHandler`? To the compiler, that's a possible scenario, thus the types don't match.

Comment: That makes sense! So what I have should be refactored then? I'm thinking I may need to update `AbstractFruitHandler` to instead have method `handle(Fruit fruit)`. And then in each implementation of `AbstractFruitHandler`,  explicitly cast the Fruit to the concrete type. Was trying to avoid having to do this.